# Making a toggle ng-click event

Tags: angularjs, toggle, angularjs-ng-click

I have been able to create a function to successfully toggle the rows in my ng-table to expand on click, however, when clicking them again they will not hide. The function in the javascript is:

```
$scope.toggle = function() {
    return !this.booleanVal;
};
```

The `booleanVal` is being a value from the `json` file (each row with its own value). Then in the HTML.

```
<p class="row_description more" ng-click="row.booleanVal = toggle()">{{row.description}</p>
<div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="row.booleanVal">
```

It works for the first click, turning the previously false `booleanVal` to `true`, however, it doesn't `toggle` back to `false`. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p class="row_description more" ng-click="row.booleanVal = !row.booleanVal">
    {{row.description}
</p>
<div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="row.booleanVal"></div>
```

Comment: I found out offline through a mentor that you can also do it this way `TestCase.prototype.toggle = function() {
  this.showMe = !this.showMe;
}` but your solution is also correct and works great.

Comment: Make sure you don't accidentally do `row.value!=row.value` like I did, expecting it to work for 10 minutes, as that is just comparing if it's not equal to ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hi please have a look here : http://jsbin.com/hefeb/1/edit

```
  $scope.toogle = function(i)
  {
    i.booleanVal = !i.booleanVal 

  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a conditional operator.

Try this:

```
<p class="row_description more" 
   ng-click="row.booleanVal =row.booleanVal?false:true">
   {{row.description}}
</p>
<div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="row.booleanVal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Use `this.row.booleanVal` in `toggle()` function
- Directly toggle your boolean in the *ngClick* directive: `ng-click="row.booleanVal = !row.booleanVal"`